# iOS Voice over, how to skip a tableview cell rather than speak "not enabled"

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover

I have a tableview with multiple cells. A couple of these cells are purely decorative, containing a divider. Using the Accessibility Inspector developer tool in Xcode whenever it hits one of these cells, it speaks "not enabled".

So part one, I'm unsure if it's best practice to Voice Over speak "not enabled" on the cell as it feels a cleaner experience and closer to the none Voice Over version to just fully skip it. However, I can imagine a case where potentially page navigation is more obvious to the user if they know all the cells, even if decorative.

If this isn't a best practice issue, how do I make it just skip the cell without saying anything?

Currently, I have tried, in storyboard, to set accessibility to fully off on these cells, and applied the same with the inner View which creates the divider:

[image]

I have also in the Attributes inspector disabled UserInteractionEnabled

In code for the cells, I have set:

```
self.divider.isAccessibilityElement = false
self.isAccessibilityElement = false
```

But, the inspector still speaks not "enabled" on these cells and the Accessibility Inspector shows the traits as 'Static Text Not Enabled'

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UITableViewCell` may be seen as a container inside which many elements are embedded *(buttons...)* and, as is, you can't have simultaneously a parent view *(the table view cell)* and its child views *(label, button...)* that are [both accessible](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#hide-elements) with VoiceOver: either your cell can be selected or its content.

In your case, you don't want the cell itself or its content to be read out by the screen reader so you must specify:

- yourCell.isAccessibilityElement = false
- yourCell.accessibilityElementsHidden = false

Following this rationale, you **skip a tableview cell rather than speak “not enabled”**.